# Drop even levels from multi-index dataset

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here is sample dataset:

```
                          |Count|
|-------------------------|     |
|Name |ID_1  |Level |ID_2 |     |
|-----|------|------|-----|-----|
|Kate |91978 |Junior|3    |13   |
|Lucy |47992 |Junior|3    |11   |
|John |37005 |Middle|2    |8    |
|Peter|42235 |Senior|1    |21   |
```

Let's say ['Name', 'ID_1', 'Level','ID_2'] are multi-index names

I want to drop all even multi-index names, meaning get rid of ['ID_1',ID_2']
So that end result looks like this:

```
              |Count|
|-------------|     |
|Name  |Level |     |
|------|------|-----|
|Kate  |Junior|13   |
|Lucy  |Junior|11   |
|John  |Middle|8    |
|Peter |Senior|21   |
```

I found this method: `df.index = df.index.droplevel(1)`

But the thing is the real dataset is too big, and dropping each second column manually is not an option.
How to drop all even columns at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of index levels to `DataFrame.droplevel`.

For instance, given the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,5)), 
                 columns=list('abcde'))
      .set_index(list('abcd'))
)
```

```
>>> df

         e
a b c d   
0 4 2 0  2
3 2 3 1  1
4 2 2 3  4
0 0 1 4  2
  4 3 4  4
```

You can do something like

```
res = df.droplevel(list(range(1, len(df.index.names), 2)))
```

```
>>> res

     e
a c   
0 2  2
3 3  1
4 2  4
0 1  2
  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Df

```
import pandas.util.testing
df =pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,8),columns=list('abcdfrtl'))
```

drop even indices; -

```
df.droplevel(df.index.names[1::2])
```

drop even columns; - Or use the loc accessor

```
new=df.iloc[:,0::2]



     a         c         f         t
0  0.069244  0.747373  0.217126  0.779653
1  0.303143  0.288040  0.234507  0.923503
2  0.195276  0.131842  0.447319  0.511451
3  0.821173  0.776493  0.827540  0.679356
```

Comment: It works only if i apply it towards usual columns, but i got multi-index

Comment: Ok, please try `df.droplevel(df.index.names[1::2])`